# SQL Server ignores indexes for UNION

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-performance

Why is SQL Server (2019 confirmed) so exceptionally bad at generating efficient plans for simple `UNION`s? Why does it often ignore suitable indexes?

This script generates my demo database:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    c1 INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    c2 DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    c3 INT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY(c1)
);

WHILE(ISNULL(@@ROWCOUNT, 0) < 1000000) -- Insert ca 2 million rows
    INSERT INTO MyTable(c2, c3)
    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 650000, GETUTCDATE()), CHECKSUM(NEWID())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 650000, GETUTCDATE()), CHECKSUM(NEWID()) FROM MyTable;

CREATE INDEX C2_MyTable ON MyTable(c2);
```

Now, this query is perfectly fast:

```
SELECT TOP 500 t1.* 
FROM
    (SELECT NULL AS c1, NULL AS c2, NULL AS c3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM MyTable) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.c2 ASC
```

And it generates a very reasonable query plan:

[image: Fast execution plan for ASC]

But now, if I only swap the sorting from `ASC` to `DESC`:

```
SELECT TOP 500 t1.* 
FROM
    (SELECT NULL AS c1, NULL AS c2, NULL AS c3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM MyTable) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.c2 DESC
```

I get a terrible and slow query plan:

[image]

Really, ~80000% of the total cost? Great. In fact, I don't even have to use `DESC` to bungle the plan, I can just omit `c1`:

```
SELECT TOP 500 t1.* 
FROM
    (SELECT NULL AS c2, NULL AS c3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT c2, c3 FROM MyTable) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.c2 ASC
```

This generates the same terrible plan and oddly enough, looking at the Sort operation it now shows `ORDER BY c2 DESC, c3 ASC`. Who even brought `c3` into this?!

Naturally, if I remove the `UNION`, SQL Server is perfectly happy to use the `C2` index for both `ASC` and `DESC` sorting.

At first I tried going at the problem using different covering indexes, table hints and whatnot, but that turned out to be a house of cards. Only after a long battle I discovered through trial & error that if I order by `c2 DESC` and **also** `c1 DESC`, I will get the fast query plan again:

```
SELECT TOP 500 t1.* 
FROM
    (SELECT NULL AS c1, NULL AS c2, NULL AS c3
     UNION ALL
     SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM MyTable) AS t1
ORDER BY t1.c2 DESC, t1.c1 DESC
```

What's up with that? Am I missing something here? Is SQL Server really too stupid to do this by itself? Is it really needed? Should I always add the clustered key to every `DESC` sort, just to be safe? Is it a bug?

NB: The tables and queries above are greatly simplified from the production db. The actual tables involved are fairly wide with a few thousands to many millions of rows.

Comment: Plans with the Merge join operator often need some messing around to get rid of sorts unfortunately. [example 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215128/3690) [example 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259853/3690) article https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation

Comment: So it's essentially a bug which everyone has to find workarounds for?